# Rendering the charts as columnrange type

Tags: highcharts

I have the following chart  I would like to render the working times intervalls as columnrange  and palcing  the charts close to the xAxis.

with this part of code in the code below

```
chart: {
    spacingTop: 0,
    paddingTop: 0,
    zoomType: 'x',

},
```

I am getting the following charts:

[image]

https://jsfiddle.net/62jq6zsd/

But I am not getting the right result.

Comment: What's the question? What is the *"right result"*, and what in what way is what you are getting wrong?

Comment: @jlbriggs: how can I bring the chartsclose to the xAxis and delete the values as well as the Highcharts.com from the generted one? Plese take a look at my added jsfiddle

Comment: See the latest update in my answer below to affect the space between the series and axis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting your code into a fiddle, I can see that nothing is plotted:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/3d3fuhbb/225/

Looking at your data, the reason is apparent. You have your data set up as;

```
{
  x: 1483358580000,
  y: 1
}
```

But the `columnrange` series type requires the data elements of `low` and `high`, with an optional/inferred `x` value.

In addition, you have points with `null` values for `x`, which does not work for Highcharts - there must always be an `x` value, whether set or inferred.

It's also unnecessary - use of `null` points to break a `line` series is needed because lines are meant to be continuous; the `columnrange` type already has the breaks built in.

And finally, you have your `x` and `y` mixed up - since you are inverting the chart, the axes swap places - `x` is the vertical axis, and `y` is the horizontal.

If your values are time, as in the `1483358580000` above, you need to specify two timestamps - one for the start, and one for the end of each bar segment.

Example from the Highcharts demo:

```
    data: [
        [-9.7, 9.4],
        [-8.7, 6.5],
        [-3.5, 9.4],
        [-1.4, 19.9],
        [0.0, 22.6],
        [2.9, 29.5],
        [9.2, 30.7],
        [7.3, 26.5],
        [4.4, 18.0],
        [-3.1, 11.4],
        [-5.2, 10.4],
        [-13.5, 9.8]
    ]
```

(in this example, the `x` value is determined by the order of the data points, and does not need to be set explicitly. In your case, you will need to specify the `x` value, since you want them all on the same line)

Demo Fiddle:

- http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/columnrange/

**{{ EDIT }}**

Using your chart as a base, here is an updated version.

Code (data based on yours, edited for demonstration)

```
xAxis: {
  categories: ['', 'Woring time'],
  title: {
    text: null
  },
  gridLineWidth: 0
},
yAxis: {
    type: 'datetime'
    },
series: [{
  data: [
            [1,1483337940000,1483337950000],
            [1,1483337970000,1483337990000],
            [1,1483338000000,1483338010000],
            [1,1483338030000,1483338070000]
        ]
}]
```

Fiddle:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/qdza1032/

**{{ Edit again for comments }}**

To reduce space between the series, you have a variety of options

1) reduce the height of your chart

2) increase the width of your bar

1/2) do both!

3) work with your axis min/max and minPadding/maxPadding settings, if you want one side of the series and not the other.

Option one, in a fiddle:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/qdza1032/1/

Option three:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/qdza1032/2/